# Graph handling library

Tags: c, graph

I need to find a library for representing and drawing graphs in C (**not C++**). I wish to find one with a GPL licence.

I have to build dynamically some graphs, and draw it. It would be perfect to find a library that has built in drawing functions, without having to convert the internal graphs to graphviz data structure.

I found [this one](http://www.dia.uniroma3.it/~gdt/gdt4/sample.php) but it is not open source.

I wish to ask for other recommendations of a library.

Comment: Have a look at [Cairo](http://cairographics.org/) or [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/).

Comment: What advantages do I have if I represent a graph using these libralies instead of directly with cgraph interface of graphviz ? How they are more convenient than others ? How can I represent the attributes of a node of a graph more convenient than directly in graphviz ?

Comment: Oops, you are right! I misunderstood the question, please ignore my previous comment (thought you were asking for a graphics library). I'm sorry about that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [igraph](http://igraph.sourceforge.net/) could be interesting to you, but I'm sorry I didn't used it (I currently use cgraph in Qt).

Such a complex library will anyway require a substantial effort to adapt your data structure.

Comment: Igraph looks interesting . Do you know a basic tutorial of how to use cgraph library ?

Comment: cgraph as a library is explained in a PDF reachable from [Using graphviz as a library](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/libguide/libguide.pdf). From a practical point, I studied QGraph project